# Terraform - output ec2 instance ids to calling shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am using **'terraform apply'** in a shell script to create multiple EC2 instances. I need to output the list of generated IPs to a script variable & use the list in another sub-script. I have defined output variables for the ips in a terraform config file - '**instance_ips**'

```
output "instance_ips" {
 value = [
  "${aws_instance.gocd_master.private_ip}",
  "${aws_instance.gocd_agent.*.private_ip}"
 ]
}
```

However, the terraform apply command is printing entire EC2 generation output apart from the output variables.

```
terraform init \
  -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" \
  -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_STATE_BUCKET_NAME" \
  -backend-config="role_arn=$PROVISIONING_ROLE" \
  -reconfigure \
  "$TERRAFORM_DIR"

OUTPUT = $( terraform apply <input variables e.g - 
                  var="aws_region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION">
                 -auto-approve \
                 -input=false \
                 "$TERRAFORM_DIR"
               )

terraform output instance_ips
```

So the 'OUTPUT' script variable content is

```
Terraform command: apply Initialising the backend...  Successfully 
configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically use this 
backend unless the backend configuration changes. Initialising provider 
plugins... Terraform has been successfully initialised!
.
.
.
aws_route53_record.gocd_agent_dns_entry[2]: Creation complete after 52s 
(ID:<zone ............................) 
aws_route53_record.gocd_master_dns_entry: Creation complete after 52s 
(ID:<zone ............................)  
aws_route53_record.gocd_agent_dns_entry[1]: Creation complete after 53s 
(ID:<zone ............................)   
Apply complete! Resources: 9 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.  Outputs: 
instance_ips = [ 10.39.209.155, 10.39.208.44, 10.39.208.251, 
10.39.209.227 ]
```

instead of just the EC2 ips.

Firing the **'terraform output instance_ips'** is throwing a **'Initialisation Required'** error which I understand means 'terraform init' is required.

Is there any way to suppress ec2 generation & just print output variables. if not, how to retrieve the IPs using 'terraform output' command w/o needing to do a terraform init ?

Comment: Are you running terraform output from the directory as the when you run terraform apply. it shouldn't need to be reinitialize again. Normally, you run terraform init before running apply.

Comment: 'terraform init' , 'terraform apply' and 'terraform output' are all run from within the same shell script in a sequence

Comment: You mention you are using `terraform output` in your script but your script only shows you capturing the output of `terraform apply`. Can you share the full thing? `terraform output` is what you want to just capture the Terraform `output` rather than the stdout from running `terraform apply`.

Comment: i have included the script section where terraform init, apply & output commands are called in sequence

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the context correctly, you can actually create a file in that directory & that file can be used by your sub-shell script. You can do it by using a `null_resource` OR "local_file".

Here is how we can use it in a modularized structure -

Using `null_resource` -

```
resource "null_resource" "instance_ips" {
  triggers {
       ip_file = "${sha1(file("${path.module}/instance_ips.txt"))}"
      }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${module.ec2.instance_ips} >> instance_ips.txt"
  }
}
```

Using `local_file` -

```
resource "local_file" "instance_ips" {
    content     = "${module.ec2.instance_ips}"
    filename = "${path.module}/instance_ips.txt"
}
```